# Cookiebot automode skip specific script

Tags: cookiebot

i installed cookiebot via the wordpress plugin and it works great.

The problem i've is that i've one script i need cookiebot to skip, but i don't find any way to do it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an option to set cookiebot automode to skip scripts

You just need to include your script with this data att

`data-cookieconsent="ignore"`

like this

`<script data-cookieconsent="ignore"></script>`

hope this helps you!